# vue life cycle method for updated vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am using Vue and Vuex. In my component I have the following code:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    address: state => state.wallet.address
  })
},
```

it works great in the UI, but what I want to do it to call a method as soon address changed its value. Any idea how I can trigger that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**watcher** might help in your case. You can create a watcher to detect the change in address computed property. the watcher will be executed once the value changed. Refer to the example attached.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      address: state => state.wallet.address
    })
  },
  watch: {
    address: function (newAddress, oldAddress) {
      // this watcher will be called once address changed
      // you can have access to previous and new values.
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Mounted is the most-often used hook in the lifecycle. mounted() is called
after DOM has been mounted so you can access  the reactive component,
templates, and DOM elements and manipulate them.
In Server Side Rendering created()is used over mounted() because
mounted() is not present in it.

---> mounted() <---

Comment: mounted and created are too early for me. since the state is first undefined and just later gets a proper value.